# Upload License file via API

Tags: cloudera

Using fresh install This suppose to be straight forward, however every time I try and upload the license I'm getting a weird error message.

I'm using curl to upload license file.

```
 curl -X POST \
  http://server_IP:7180/api/v13/cm/license \
  -H 'authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data;
  -F 'id=@C:\Users\admin\Desktop\license_new.txt'
```

Response Message:

```
{ "message" : "No multipart with content id license found, request content type : multipart/form-data;boundary=--------------------------876318151600001394250578" }
```

Any ideas?

```
Version: Cloudera Enterprise 5.8.3 (#8 built by jenkins on 20161019-1014 git: 518f0d6d44abc87bc392646e4369a20c8192b7cf)
Java Version: 1.7.0_75
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with:

```
curl -i -X POST -F license=@<license file> -u <username>:<password> -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" http://<cm-hostname>:7180/api/v13/cm/license
```

Comment: Thanks @jedijs for your help, it seems like the I should have set  `license=` instead of `id=`